# Can't attach animation to script

Tags: animation, unity

I'm working on a little game (which is also my first one) and I want to insert a splash screen at the beginning (after the Unity one).
I've finally achieved to add a fade-in and a fade-out transistion when the splash screen starts and ends, but the fade out is activated by a button and I wont to play it simply after a certain time.
I've made a script for that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class FadeInOut_2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animation anim;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        anim.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();

        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel + 1);
    }

}
```

The problem is: when I try to attach the animation the Inspector refuses to do it.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling GetComponent on anim, when anim *is* an Animation component?

Comment: @jhocking is right. You have already assigned a clip to anim, so there is no need to call GetComponent. Just say `anim.Play();`

Comment: just another bit of info: you can use transform.GetComponent<COMPONENT>() to access another component on the same object.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't waiting on the animation so once you play it `Application.LoadLevel` just does its thing and you wont notice the animation.

First, you'll need a way to wait on the animation which could be a simple coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator WaitForAnimation ( Animation animation )
{
do
    {
        yield return null;
    } while ( animation.isPlaying );
}
```

And then use it to yield before calling `Application.LoadLevel`:

```
    ...
    anim.Play();
    yield WaitForAnimation(anim);

    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel + 1);
}
```

Also, you don't need to call `GetComponent<Animation>` on an `Animation`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you created a coroutine but never called it, by using StartCoroutine().

Comment: The `Start()` function of a monobehaviour can be used as a coroutine without calling the `StartCoroutine()`.

Comment: @Lasse interesting, googled up and everybody seems to confirm this but could not find any documentation about it, could you provide one?

Comment: @NikaKasradze I'm afraid right now there isn't much more than what is on this documentation page: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html It seems to be one of the many badly documented features of Unity.